# Transparent Legend with pandas.plot

Tags: python, pandas, plot, transparency

I checked the documentation of pandas plot

[pd.df.plot](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.18.1/generated/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html)

but I could not find any option to make the legend transparent

I know how to do it with matplotlib

```
subplot.legend(loc='best', fancybox=True, framealpha=0.5)
```

but I need to use pandas dataframe plot

Any idea?

Answer (score 7):

Plotting a Pandas `DataFrame` returns a Matplotlib `axis` object. Save this to a variable, then adjust the legend settings afterwards:

```
ax = df.plot()
ax.legend(loc='best', fancybox=True, framealpha=0.5)
```

Example:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib

df = pd.DataFrame({"A": [0,1]})
ax = df.plot()
ax.legend(loc='best', fancybox=True, framealpha=0.5)
ax.plot()
```

[image]